# What are some packages for elastic cache in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am using Laravel and i've read the docs but my question is, is there any packages that for elastic cache or is there any websites that have an implementation of it?

any links would greatly help!

Comment: ever checked where `composer` get things? there is [laravel-elasticsearch](https://packagist.org/packages/cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch) in packagist. just whenever you need libs for laravel, go there.

Comment: Its an elastic search. What i'm after is elastic caching. Thanks for the link anyway

Comment: sorry, misread your title.. [here elasticache](https://packagist.org/packages/dpollard/elasticache-laravel), as i said.. check packagist.. sometimes people already invented things you need.

Comment: Thanks! will check it

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this package: https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent

I think it pretty good to start with.

Comment: Uhmm is this somewhat related to elastic caching? I guess elastic search is different from elastic caching.